# App Script Hyperlink Download PDF

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way via a hyperlink to only create a PDF of a specific sheet using a hyperlink formula? If I do not hide the sheet it will also add the second sheet to the pdf export. I tried using GID in the URL, but that only reopened the current PDF or exported it as CSV. This is created dynamically via script when the sheet opens.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Let's say you want to publish only Sheet 1 as PDF of your spreadsheet file:

1. In google sheets, go to File and choose Publish to the Web.
2. Under Link tab, choose Sheet 1 and choose [PDF Document format](https://imgur.com/a/XNjvk).
3. Copy the link and run it on the browser. It will download Sheet 1 only.

Notice also the URI format:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS-fqXA_S5rj18aVSe6bj1HA2AUYCaYr2BNLbN_w1a_B77QlgnRKB5y3QUBTv0wIu6KxkOm_qq71m6H/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=pdf
```

If you want to publish a different sheet as PDF, copy the 'gid' of that sheet and assign it to the 'gid' value in the link.

Comment: So the Spreadsheet needs to be published I am assuming or this whole idea will not work.

Comment: Yes. You can always 'unpublish' it later if you want. Just give it a try